# PSD.js Is not pulling in layers from some PSD files

Tags: javascript, node.js, psd

Has anyone had this issue? I have lots of PSD files that I am parsing with PSD.js and for the most part it's all good but, there are the odd few PSD files that are not pulling in the layers.

I get the layers like this:

```
var psd = PSD.fromFile(filename);
psd.parse();
var layers = psd.tree.descendants();
```

So in the specific psd file console.log(layers) shows an empty array, but with all the other files it shows a full array of layers.

Does anyone know why some of the PSD files are not showing layers?

Comment: siblings(): get all sibling tree nodes including the current one (e.g. all layers in a folder)

Comment: that still shows an empty array

Comment: if it works for some and doesn't for some could very well be issues with the PSD itself.

Comment: siblings() doesn't work for any of them

Comment: any idea what could be the issue with the psd? it's just a normal psd with multiple layers.

Comment: I haven't used PSD.js before but i imagine getting the file should be async but i could be wrong

Comment: in fact it looks like it's something to do with file size, when the PSD is bigger than about 25MB it doesn't read it properly.

Comment: Ah here we go, it's because the Psd was 16bit not 8bit

Comment: nice find, makes sense :)

Comment: Thanks for replying anyway :)